# Django - Do I need to check for IntegrityErrors when validating a ModelForm?

Tags: django, validation, exception, django-models, django-forms

I"ve got a simple question:

Do I need to listen for `IntegrityErrors` when I am already checking a submitted ModelForm's integrity with `is_valid`?

My code looks like this at the moment and I am thinking about removing the try catch:

```
def edit_object(request, object_id):
    o = get_object_or_404(ObjectModel, pk=object_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ObjectForm(request.POST, instance=o)
        try:
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('namespace:startpage')
            else:
                return render(request, 'namespace/editpage.html', {'form': form,})
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, 'namespace/editpage.html', {'form': form,})
    return render(request, 'namespace/editpage.html', {'form': ObjectForm(instance=o),})
```

Since I never even save my object if the data is not valid, I should never be able to produce an IntegrityError-exception, right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you could still encounter an `IntegrityError` if you have other [constraints](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/) on your model, e.g. a `ForeignKey` should be unique.

Comment: This depends on your model and if there are any potential race conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your comments you two, now I know what to look at :)